# Make a Change Log table which logs the changes in drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a Change log table which show if there's been a change in the drop down menu.
For example i am working with a worksheet and i have one select menu Results which has options like Positive, Negative, Unknown. I want if anyone changes from Positive to negative or anything else it should log in the change log table with a time stamp.

Currently i have a version which works with the input fields but it is not working when i am making changes in the select field (drop down menu).

This is the code i am using for input fields and this is working fine.

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'input', function()
  {
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
   }
   ).on('change','input', function(){
    var prev = $(this).data('val');
    var current = $(this).val();
    var date1 = Date();
     if (prev !== current) {
         $(this).css("color", $currentDayColor);
         $specimenInfo = "";

    if((prev != current) && (prev!= null) && (prev != " ")){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + $specimenInfo + 'The Prev Value is :' + prev +' Which was changed on :'+ date1+'<br>';
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML + $specimenInfo + ' The Current Value is :' + current +' Which was changed on :'+ date1 + '<br>';
    console.log("Prev value " + prev);
    console.log("New value " + current);
    }
     };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code with input fields is working fine then you just need to replace the 'input' with 'select' in your selector. Like this:

```
$(document).on('focusin', 'select', function()
  {
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
   }
   ).on('change','select', function(){
    var prev = $(this).data('val');
    var current = $(this).val();
    var date1 = Date();
     if (prev !== current) {
         $(this).css("color", $currentDayColor);
         $specimenInfo = "";

    if((prev != current) && (prev!= null) && (prev != " ")){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + $specimenInfo + 'The Prev Value is :' + prev +' Which was changed on :'+ date1+'<br>';
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML + $specimenInfo + ' The Current Value is :' + current +' Which was changed on :'+ date1 + '<br>';
    console.log("Prev value " + prev);
    console.log("New value " + current);
    }
     };
});
```

Comment: When i am trying to do both it is not working. Like instead of input i have select, but when i put $(document).on('focusin','input', 'select', function() only input is working not select

Comment: you cannot do both like this, that is the wrong syntax/command. you can write the whole thing twice (not the prettiest code) or refactor to use function.

Comment: i have one more question that instead of showing the value of the select field it showing me numbers. For eg: If it's positive then 214, negative then 212 and so..

Comment: .val() reads the value of the selected option, not the text. Either have the same 'Positive', 'Negative' etc as the value (same as the text) or use $(this).find('option:selected').text()

Comment: And Where i should do that in my code is it before my function or after where i mentioned my console.log

Comment: Replace $(this).val() with $(this).find('option:selected').text() where ever you have it.

Comment: I am doing the same functionality for Select2 and it is not working.